# Apply bitmap mask to image on html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas

Good morning, i have a canvas with a background image, i need to put another image over it and apply a mask on it to have some transparency. Here you can find a link to a sample of the final result i need. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
imagecontext.drawImage(mask, 0, 0, width, height);
imagecontext.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
imagecontext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

http://codepo8.github.io/canvas-masking/