# Draw mask on canvas image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[image]

Is this possible in canvas to do something like this on screen?
Basically I want to:

1. Upload any image to canvas [DONE]
2. Put any type of mask on it (here on screen this circle) [DONE]
3. Move,rotate and scale image [DONE]
4. Be able to see rest of the image around the mask(it should be darkened) like on this screen

I try various ways to render it with
`ctx.globalCompositeOperation`
but I only get image inside the mask and rest of the image is covered by background of canvas (although i can move or rotate image)

Edit:
When I rotate it it should look like on the second picture
And then i want to clip this rectangle and save to file (which also is DONE)
[image]

Comment: Is there any need to put the background image onto the main canvas? Could you just have a couple of divs (or a suitably rotated canvas) behind it with the original image as background and a semi transparent mask over it?

Comment: @AHaworth I make edit to my original post - when i rotate it or move it, the whole image should move below mask - then i want to clip and save to file only portion of image inside mask - this is something like photo editor. Do you think that is entirely possible without using canvas? Only with divs and manipulating backgrounds? Using Canvas was in my original requiremenets of project, but I think I do not have to necessarily use it and they can be changed

Comment: I wasn’t suggesting you didn’t use canvas for the main part, only whether your background could be done another way.

Answer (score 0):

The question has already cut out the image required so one way of getting what is needed is to draw the whole image on a canvas, draw a mask over it and then place the already obtained image over that.

However, it is possible to do it the other way round.

Draw the image on a canvas, scaling, skewing, stretching, rotating it as required.

Then draw the semi transparent overlay on it e.g.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0,0,width,height);
ctx.fillStyle = “rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
ctx.fill();
```

cutting out the required mask. Without knowing exactly what shape is required it’s not possible to give the exact code for this but see for example [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711841/apply-bitmap-mask-to-image-on-html5-canvas](http://bitmap-mask-to-image-on-html5-canvas) which describes how to remove part of a mask.